# AttributeError: 'KeyboardButtonUrl' object has no attribute 'data' ошибка в telethon

Tags: python, python-3.x, telethon

всем! Я пишу маленькую программу с помощью telethon. Я перечитал мануалы, но ничего не нашел. 
Вот нужный код:

```
button_data = msg.reply_markup.rows[0].buttons[0].data
```

Ошибка:

```
    button_data = msg.reply_markup.rows[0].buttons[0].data
AttributeError: 'KeyboardButtonUrl' object has no attribute 'data'
```

И да "data" это последнее слово ряде.

Comment: А что он должен выполнять? Должен на что-то нажимать но у него не получается, так?

Comment: Он не нашел кнопку по которой нужно нажать.